# Retrieving a table alias

Tags: php, postgresql, alias

I have several queries that have a same filter.

For example:

Filter:

```
$criteria = "AND id_student = 1 AND id_major = 2 ";
```

Query 1:

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM student AS t0
LEFT JOIN major AS t1 ON t0.id_major = t1.id
WHERE 1=1 ";
```

Query 2:

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM lecturer AS t0
LEFT JOIN major AS t1 ON t0.id_major = t1.id
LEFT JOIN student AS t2 ON t2.id_major = t1.id
WHERE 1=1 "
```

It will be run as

```
$query1.$criteria
```

and

```
$query2.$criteria
```

As you can see, this will yield a query error, since id_major is ambiguous.

My problem is, that this query is very big in number, so I prefer not to hard-code and change the $criteria and $query individually.

I've tried to change the $criteria into

```
$criteria = "AND student.id_student = 1 AND major.id_major = 2 ";
```

But it does no better, it gave me errors of "did you mean t0", "did you mean t2", etc.

So, can I do something like, get an alias of a table? So I can put it in the $criteria

```
$criteria = "AND (get-alias-code).id_student = 1 AND (get-alias-code).id_major = 2 ";
```

Or any other method?

I am not the primary developer of this program, just a bug-fixer so I cannot change much of this program (because those queries may affect another page).

Comment: and you said you are a bug fixer

Comment: Your WHERE clauses in those queries... `WHERE 1=1`, really? The only situation I know these from are blind SQL injection attacks.

Comment: You can make alias like `student as s`, `major as m` and write $criteria as `s.id_student = 1 and m.id_major = 2`, or just work without aliases at all and use $criteria like `student.id_student = 1 AND major.id_major = 2`

Comment: @RomanPekar Most part of the program are made by others, including the queries. Therefore if possible, it is better not to disturb the queries.

Comment: My guess is OP knows neither table names nor aliases. `WHERE 1=1` is a typical test condition used in [blind SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Blind_SQL_Injection) attacks, so this whole question seems fishy to me.

Comment: @cuewizchris ah see what you mean now

Comment: @cuewizchris WHERE 1=1 is used by the queries in the program, since the syntax for $condition are usually begins with "AND .... "

Comment: @cuewizchris `WHERE 1 = 1` is also used as a lazy programmer's query building shortcut so you don't have to keep track of whether or not you need to prepend `AND` to a condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the aliases you have for your tables already, and set the criteria to be

```
$criteria = "AND t0.`id_student`='1' AND t1.`id_major`='2' ";
```

I strongly recommend using backtics and ticks as well, it helps avoiding funny mistakes with table or field names like 'order' :)

Then all you need to ensure is that the table that needs the criteria applied gets the correct alias every time

Edit:
Hm...alternatively, you can remove aliasing from all queries. 
I honestly don't think that there's any mysql feature to get the aliases for tables.  You could run a string analyser code snippet to find them (knowing all table names it may not even be hard to do) but that looks like a very ugly solution IMHO.

Comment: The problem is that there exist queries that doesn't have same alias... If they are the same I would not be asking this question, no? Thanks anyway.

Comment: So there really is no other workaround than editing all those variables?

Comment: Well I sadly do not know of any, sorry.

Comment: Okay then, I guess I'll say the same to my supervisor and hopefully made those programmers synchronize or remove their aliases, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know away to handle it on sql but you can handle it with on array for example

```
$alias[1]["student"] = "t0"; // it means on query 1 your alias for student is t0
```

now you can use this variable on your filter

```
$criteria = "AND ".$alias[1]["student"].".id_student = 1 AND ".$alias[1]["major"].".id_major = 2 ";
```

I think it's one of fast ways to change your filter without changing all of queries.
hope It helps

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole thing in an outer query like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM (".$query1.") a ".$criteria;
```

Assuming of course that the original query didn't create multiple columns with the same name, you can now reference them without the alias.